# make debug option that echoes (prints) shell function arguments

Tags: makefile

Is there make debug option that prints all executions of shell function?

For example if I have makefile

```
contents := $(shell echo foo)

all:
```

I want it to print "echo foo".

Answer (score 0):

You can supply your own program as a shell, that will echo the commands and do whatever else you need.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html:

> 5.3.2 Choosing the Shell
>
> The program used as the shell is taken from the variable `SHELL`. If this variable is not set in your makefile, the program `/bin/sh` is used as the shell. The argument(s) passed to the shell are taken from the variable `.SHELLFLAGS`. The default value of `.SHELLFLAGS` is `-c` normally, or `-ec` in POSIX-conforming mode.

So, run:

```
SHELL=mysneakyprogram make all
```

Each command will be passed to `mysneakyprogram` with a `-c` argument.

The catch is: this will also apply to normal commands that build targets, not only `$(shell ...)`; I don't think you can distinguish the two cases.